# Javascript: using value in array to access variable

Tags: javascript, arrays, variables

I have multiple variables named for instance "s11" and "s12" etc.

```
var s11 = 0;
var s12 = 0;
```

In addition to that, I also have an array containing all the names of these variables.

```
var wA = new Array("s11", "s12");
```

The values in the array are added automatically in the script later on, depending on user activity.

My problem is that I would like for example the variable "s11" to ++ every time it occurs as a value in the array. Can this be done?

Comment: Can you use an array instead of the "multiple variables named s11 s12"?

Comment: Yes, but you'd probably have to write an if statement for every variable that could possibly be incremented. Could you make a second array thats indexed with the field names and increment that instead? eg `var fields = {"s11":0,"s12":0};`

Comment: You mean I can simply input the count into the wA array? Then I would not need the variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using variables, will make your life hard. Here is one approach that does both. Use associative array, like this:

```
var count = {};
var wA = new Array("s11", "s12");


function updateArray(value) {

  wA.push(value);

  if(! (value in count) ) {
    count[value] = 0;
  }
  count[value]++;
}
```

Then use it like:

```
updateArray("s11");
updateArray("s12");
```

Now `count` will look like: `{s11: 1, s12: 1}` & `wA` will look like: `['s11', 's12']`

Comment: Seems to be working perfectly! I will just double check everything before pressing solved.

Comment: @Thomas: yea, also don't forget to +1 ;-)

Comment: Yes, it works as beautifully as a sunset on the eastern archipelago of Sweden, with a soft breeze running through your hair!

Answer (score 0):

You could use the `eval()` function. It runs any code given as argument. For example, to `++` each variable when its name appears in the array, use:

```
for(variablename in wA){ // or any other way to loop through the array
    eval(variablename + "++");
}
```

Also, you could use the owner object like an associative array. If the variables are global, just use `window`.

```
for(variablename in wA){ // or any other way to loop through the array
    window[variablename]++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If your `s` variables are global then you could dot he following :

```
for (var i = wA.length; i--;)
  window[wA[i]] ++;
```

Answer (score 0):

If they are global variables, you can grab them from the `window` object using bracket notation:

```
window[wA[0]]; // 0
```

Otherwsie, I would recommend using an object instead of variables:

```
var myVars = {
    s11 : 0,
    s12 : 0
};

myVars[wA[0]]; // 0
```

The only other way is using [`eval`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval), which might be dangerous if you're dealing with user input.

Answer (score 0):

If your variables are global you can do as shown below

```
s11 = 10;
s12 = 12;


var i = 11;

var wA = new Array(window["s" + i++], window["s" + i]);
```

Otherwise you will have to declare the variables in a scope , for e.g: using `this`

```
this.s11 = 10;
this.s12 = 12;


var i = 11;

var wA = new Array(this["s" + i++], this["s" + i]);
```

Or you can use a loop to push elements

```
var wA = [];
for(var i=11; i<=12; i++){
    wA.push(this["s" + i]);
}
```

NOTE: starting and end values of `i` depends on your requirement and implementation